# CSS Stylesheet Problem

Tags: css, safari

I'm having a problem getting my CSS to work properly in Safari. It was working fine before, but I had to change the file to .php from .css for an unrelated reason. Before, the background would be the dark gray (#CCCCCC) but it appears that the first body{} doesn't apply anymore according to Safari's Web Inspector. Why could this be happening?

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>

body{
background-color:#CCCCCC;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
body, td, div, input, textarea {
font-family:verdana,arial,serif;
font-size: 10pt;
}
```

Comment: do you have a link to this page?

Comment: With that exact css, it renders fine in Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it. For anyone else that has this problem, make sure that the `@charset` has nothing, even whitespace or a new line before it.

Comment: Could you please provide the full snippet with @charset included?